# Automatic timeout for launchd jobs

Tags: macos, timeout, kill, launchd

I have a launchd job that I've configured to run my unit tests.  Every now and then, the unit tests will hang (usually because of some bad code).  I know that my test usually only take a couple minutes to run.  When they do hang, I usually don't notice it for about an hour, at which point I have to pop open Activity Monitor and forcibly kill my tests manually.  I want launchd to do this for me.  How can I have launchd automatically kill my job (if it's still running) after a certain amount of time?

I've been looking over the [launchd man page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html), and I've noticed a couple promising keys (like `TimeOut` and `ExitTimeOut`), but the wording on the descriptions seems like it's not quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with `TimeOut` and `ExitTimeOut`, I've concluded that there doesn't seem to be a way for launchd to kill processes after a certain time interval.

I ended up adding the needed code to my program itself.  (My program does more than just unit tests)

Answer (score 2):

launchd has no way of knowing or caring about anything your process does. As long as it goes a few seconds without exiting, it's happy.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: These are semi-raw ideas, not a polished solution.)

One possibility is using the watchdog functionality of launchd. If you can customize your unit tests to touch a file when it starts, you could have a separate launchd task start up when it senses that file. If the unit test script doesn't delete the file within a specified time interval, then it should be killed. To do this, you could have the watchdog task launch a script that gets the PID of your unit tests, sleep for the desired interval, then kill the unit tests if that process is still running. YMMV.

Comment: This is similar to what I ended up implementing, except that mine runs as a second thread within my program.